# What's the translation of "rack focus" in French?

Tags: traduction

Rack focus [is a](https://www.studiobinder.com/blog/rack-focus-shot-camera-movement-angles/#:%7E:text=A%20rack%20focus%20is%20the,or%20large%20changes%20of%20focus.):

> filmmaking technique of changing the focus of the lens during a continuous shot. When a shot “racks,” it moves the focal plane from one object in the frame to another.

What's the translation of "rack focus" in French?

[Google translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=fr&text=rack%20focus&op=translate) and [Linguee](https://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=auto&query=rack+focus) didn't help.

---

Example of rack focus:

[image]

Comment: I can't understand why it's called **rack** focus. Is it an analogy with a focus distance going back and forth (in a sort of sawtooth shape)? Is it linked to the verb "to rack" (but I see only "tourmenter", "torturer")?

Comment: @XouDo rack comes from rack and pinion: See this please/https://www.cinematography.net/edited-pages/FocusTerms.htm See the gif of rack and pinion for gears; it is the same idea in older movie cameras, apparently: https://technologystudent.com/gears1/gears4.htm

Comment: @Lambie thanks, that's interesting, you're welcome to post your comment as an answer on  [What's the etymology of "rack focus"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/311004/3023)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called *succession de mises au point sélectives*.

> Quand on tourne en longue focale avec l’iris largement ouvert pour réduire la profondeur de champ, ces mises au point sélectives (*rack focus* chez les Anglo-Saxons) exigent beaucoup de précision et de concentration...

Source: http://julie-allain.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Technique_de_point.pdf

Comment: Je me suis rendue compte qu'il s'agit de changer la longuer focale pendant la même prise pour changer la mise au point sur une chose A à une chose B.

Comment: @Lambie Non, la longueur focale n'est pas modifiée lors d'un *rack focus* (cette longueur est toujours considérée pour une mise au point à l'infini).

Comment: Rack focus, also known as pulling focus or racking focus, is a camera-based filmmaking technique in which the **focus changes over the course of the shot from one focal plane to another**. https://www.masterclass.com/articles/rack-focus-guide#:~:text=Rack%20focus%2C%20also%20known%20as,stylistic%20and%20visual%20storytelling%20purposes.

Comment: @Lambie Tu semble confondre l'anglais ***focus*** et le français **focale**. Changer le *focus*, c'est à dire la mise au point, ne change en rien la longueur focale d'un objectif qui reste généralement constante lors d'un *rack focus*. C'est en particulier le cas sur la video de la question. Changer la longueur focale, c'est zoomer ou dézoomer. Les deux opérations (mise au point et zoom) sont indépendantes.

Comment: @jlliagre Pourtant, j'ai reçue  3 petits points. "La bascule de point, c'est-à-dire le changement de mise au point [FOCUS] au cours d'une même prise de vue vidéo", that is to say, a change of focus during the same video shot.

Comment: @Lambie Oui, changer la mise au point, c'est bien changer le *focus*, mais ce n'est pas changer la **focale**. Rien à voir avec ta réponse, c'est à ton premier commentaire ici que je réagissait. Tu as écrit *Je me suis rendue compte **qu'il s'agit de changer la longueur focale** pendant la même prise*. C'est inexact. On ne change pas la longueur focale durant un *rack focus*.

Comment: @Lambie Et ce n'est pas une histoire de traduction puisqu'on dit la même chose en anglais ([focal length](https://www.masterclass.com/articles/basic-photography-101-guide-to-understanding-focal-length#focal-length-comparison-in-camera-lenses)).

Comment: @EricDuminil Yes, it is missing the point but it is nevertheless not completely wrong. I would say using the singular is its unique mistake. *Mises au point sélectives* or better *Succession de mises au point sélectives* would work and the linked document is fine.

Comment: "Succession de mises au point sélectives" convient bien. Merci pour la suggestion!

Answer (score 4):

That would be *[transfert de point](https://videonline.info/quest-ce-quun-transfert-de-point/#:%7E:text=cette%20op%C3%A9ration%20consiste%20simplement%20%C3%A0,qui%20op%C3%A8re%20un%20transfert%20fluide.)* although the expression seems to be very rare, otherwise a full sentence like *basculer la mise au point d'un sujet à un autre*.

Answer (score 4):

> La bascule de point, quèsaco ?
>
> 4'44' - (en anglais) La bascule de point, c'est-à-dire le changement
> de mise au point au cours d'une même prise de vue vidéo (rack
> focusing, en anglais), est une astuce très prisée par certains
> réalisateurs. Explications...

[bascule de point défini dans Télérama](https://www.telerama.fr/cinema/la-bascule-de-point-quesaco,157677.php#0)

Origin of term rack:

This CENTURY CAMERA, Model No. 16 was manufactured by the Century Camera Company from approximately 1900 to 1902. It was constructed of solid mahogany with dovetail workmanship and covered in cowhide leather. It featured a double extension mahogany bed, attached with piano hinge for stability. The brass hardware is highly polished and lacquered. **Focusing was adjusted by a duel rack and pinion adjustment, with a long extension bellows.**

[image: Prentis Drew and 2 guys photo]
[prentis drews vintage camera collection](https://2guysphoto.wordpress.com/2011/10/17/prentis-drews-vintage-film-camera-collection/)

Rack and pinion are the terms that describe a gear assembly.

As seen here: [rack and pinion gears_animation](https://technologystudent.com/gears1/gears4.htm)

Comment: Also here: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profondeur_de_champ_(cin%C3%A9ma)#Bascule_de_point

Answer (score 3):

En plus de la *bascule de point* identifiée dans une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/49867) et l'[idée](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/49865) de *basculer*, on trouve aussi le *rattrapage de mise au point* ([GDT](https://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8353964) : « Changement de la profondeur de champ dans un plan, qui force le regard du spectateur à aller d'un centre d'intérêt à un autre. ») et le *plan de mise au point suivie* (pour la cooccurrence avec *shot*) ([Termium](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=RACK%20FOCUS&index=enw&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs)).

Answer (score 0):

The person to take care of the focus of the camera is called a ['focus puller'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focus_puller) or 'first assistant camera'. In French this is 'premier assistant opérateur'.

When we look into the tasks of that person then we come across a term like 'follow focus' the thing on the camera to regulate and smoothly change the focal plane. In french this is explained as

LES TECHNIQUES DE MISE AU POINT Vincent Georgelin, Aurore Kleiman, Romain Marcel

> Un [follow-focus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Follow_focus), que l’on pourrait traduire maladroitement en français par **« déport de commande de mise au point »**, est un système qui permet de contrôler la bague de mise au point de la caméra sans toucher à l’objectif lui-même."